# Why does PostMan always show "too many errors" after 100 lines of code?

Tags: javascript, postman, postman-pre-request-script, postman-testcase

Im quite confused about an error message in the PostMan Code-Editor. It becomes visible after 100 lines of code:

e.g.

```
tests["good test"] = true; //written 100 times
```

Postman displays a warning marker on line 100:
[image: warning]

On mouseover, this error message is shown

[image: too many errors]

But why? The code seems to be syntactically correct, even if it makes no sense semantically.

Comment: Try linting your code in your IDE before requesting with Postman. (E.g JSLint)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its a known bug according [this GitHub issue.](https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/3385)